# Cocoa - Present NSViewController programmatically LIKE "Show option" in storyboard (Without being a Modal)

Tags: cocoa, presentviewcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to present an NSViewController and there are 3 API's available.

```
presentAsModalWindow()

presentAsSheet()

present(....) for popover
```

But I want to simply present without the ViewController to become modal.
I found that in storyboard there is an option "Show". If you connect with any action then it will present the view controller and it will not be modal. But in code, I am not able to find a similar option.

NOTE: I want it should present exactly like how it did with presentAsModal without NewController being a Modal.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. We need to create a new window and embedd in new Window controller.

```
    let vc = MyViewController()
    let myWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: vc)
    myWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    let windowVC = NSWindowController(window: myWindow)
    windowVC.showWindow(self)
```